# How to get last 25 item of an array?

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

Let's say i need to get last 3 items in this array.

```
{8,9,10}
```

How can I do that with high performance approach when the array has millions of items?

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    unnest((select arraycolumn from table where id=1)) 
    WITH ORDINALITY as t(a1, num) 
ORDER BY t.num DESC 
LIMIT 25;
```

This takes 8 seconds to get last 25 items from an array that has 16 million items. I think there should be a much faster way than that.

Comment: What have you tried so far, why do you think what you tried has performance issues?

Comment: It would be foolishness to have arrays with millions of items in Postgres to begin with. Make that a *table*.

Comment: yes i get it now so i will definitely not do that..

Answer (score 0):

Try a slice:

```sql
select arraycolumn[array_upper(arraycolumn,1)-24 : array_upper(arraycolumn,1)]
from my_table 
where id = 1
```

Comment: thank you Klin...yes this works much faster like executed in 220 ms. Is there any even better way to pull this query runtime below 100 ms?

Comment: I do not think so. Btw, on my machine with 16 million integer array it takes 92 ms.

Comment: i think your pc makes the difference...well thank u again.

Comment: Try this for a small improvement:
select a[array_length(a,1)-24 : 2147483647] 
from (
    select arraycolumn from table where id = 1
    ) sub(a);

that will be slightly faster

Comment: @cinfis: And use `array_upper()` instead of `array_length()`, which is potentially wrong.